# iReport-5.6.0 is not working

Tags: ireport

I installed iReport-5.6.0 on my system. I have jadk - 1.6.0_37 installed on my machine.

When I double click on iReport icon on my desktop, initially it shows loading cursor for 1-2 seconds and then disappeares. After that there is no responce. 
I am not getting exactly what happening or what do I need to configure.

I edited ireport.config file and added path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin". But its giving me following message:

[image]

When I am clicking on Ok its sying need to specify userdir using command --userdir.
Can someone please help me to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution :)

I replaced installation directory from **"program files/jaspersoft/"** to **"program files(x86)"** and updated my jdk path in **ireport.config**. Now its working fine.